# How to correctly define that a finish date has not been reached yet

Tags: mysql, database

Having an experience record as a example.

I started working at Google at 2016-05-12

```
started_at = 2016-05-12
```

I am currently working at Google

```
finished_at = null
```

What would be the correct way to define on database that a date has not been reached yet?

I have accomplished this just by asking for `is null`, but I feel like this is a pretty bad approach, but, on the other hand, adding another column(isFinished) just to store true or false seemed bad to me too... So...

How do you do it?

Comment: `NULL` is a fine way to represent an unknown date.

Comment: Can the column contain a date in the future, or will it only be `null` until the date has been reached?

Comment: @GordonLinoff but it is not completely unknown, we know that it is in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many organizations uses different ways to store "future unknown date" , it usually goes by what your prefer best:

- Use your way, by storing `NULL` values to represent an unfinished date.
- Use a default "Open end date" like 31-dec-2999
- Add an indication column indicating whether it's an active record or not `ind_active(1/0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks fine to me. if it's `NULL` then it means you are still on the roll. Other than that, you can as well have a `bit` field like `Isfinished` which can be set to `true` `false`

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon mentioned in a comment, it is perfectly fine to use `NULL` to represent an unknown date. However, if you are intending that the column may contain a date in the future, and you want to check for either an unknown date, or a date that has not occurred yet, then you will need to perform two checks.

```
SELECT *
FROM job_history jh
WHERE jh.finish_date is null or jh.finish_date < CURDATE();
```